# Cross-browser testing with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, cross-browser

I'm trying to run this code to perform some action in Chrome and Firefox, but when I run the test runner Chrome starts and the test cases are failing in Chrome, then Firefox opens and test cases work just fine in Firefox.

I've tried for loop and a couple of things that didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import pytest
import time
Chrome=wd.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
Firefox=wd.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe")
class TestLogin():
    @pytest.fixture()
    def setup1(self):
        browsers=[Chrome, Firefox]
        for i in browsers:
            self.driver= i
            i.get("https://www.python.org")
            time.sleep(3)

        yield
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.close()

    def test_Python_website(self,setup1):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("downloads").click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: See your indentation - that `yield` is only done once, after the `for` loop. `self.driver` will always be set to Firefox then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicit `sleep`'s, you should wait for the element:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest
import time

Chrome=wd.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
Firefox=wd.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe")

class TestLogin():
    @pytest.fixture()
    def setup1(self):
        browsers = [Chrome, Firefox]
        for i in browsers:
            self.driver = i
            i.get("https://www.python.org")

        yield
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_Python_website(self, setup1):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        downloads = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, "downloads"))
        downloads.click()
```

Note: You probably want `self.driver.quite()`, as this will close the window and cause the browser process to close down as well. The call to `self.driver.close()` will only close the window, but will leave the firefox.exe or chrome.exe process running in memory after the test finishes.